# bounded function and compact issue

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Here is the problem, i have a definite fonction on an open set and I feel that the question is asking to use a compact argument

let $f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous, we also admit that $\lim_{\lVert x\rVert \to\infty}f(x) =+\infty$.

1)Prove that $f$ is bounded lowerly.

2)prove that $\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R^n}}f(x)$ is reached

So what I tried to do : $\mathbb{R^n}$ is an open set but it is known that all closed and bounded intervals of $\mathbb{R^n}$ are compacts.
So I decided to proceed this way :

let A $\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ a compact with $T_A$ its induced topology possible because $\mathbb{R^n}$ is a finite dimensional set. Basing on Tychonoff's theorem saying that a product of compacts is a compact, let's take the known set $\forall i \in \{1,..,n\}$ $\forall a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}$, $\prod_{i=1}^n[a_i;b_i] \subset A$ which is a compact.

I want to prove that $f$ is lowerly bounded so I use my admitted hypothesis that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R^n}$ so it would mean it is continuous on all of its closed subsets, so continuous on all of its compact because $\mathbb{R^n}$ is a finite dimensional set (I don't remember well but it seems to me that it was a necessary and sufficient condition to say that compacts are equivalent to closed and bounded sets).

And finally because it is continuous on a compact and has its value in $\mathbb{R}$
 then, $f$ would be lowerly bounded and reach its infimum but not its supremum because we supposed $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=+\infty$. And then answer the two questions at the same time.

**Question 1** : Can I just take a compact subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ just the way I did and finally conclude with my $f$ function generalizing it is bounded on all $\mathbb{R^n}$ ? I just feel it isn't enough.

**Question 2** : $\mathbb{R^n}$ is an open set, I don't understand how is it possible to just take a gathering of compacts and then "globalizing" the results to an open one.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I would personally go about this by showing that $f$ has a unique extension to a map from the $n$-sphere (seen as the one-point compactification of real space) into the real line with a point at infinity added (which is homeomorphic to $(0,1]$). The result then just uses the fact that the image of a compact space is compact and any compact subset of the real line has an infimum (which is attained in this case because the image is compact)

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
So if I understood well, you'd create an application definited on the n-sphere because of the compact and non-bordered property of the n-sphere and so it would ressemble to : $f:S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty\}$
is it right ?

Comment: It might help you to proceed on 1 as follows: there is a radius $R$ outside of which $f$ is lower-bounded by $1$, as a consequence of going to infinity.  Inside the (compact) ball of radius $R$, $f$ is bounded because of continuity.  Therefore there exists a finite lower bound on $f$, the minimum of $1$ and the lower-bound inside the ball.

Comment: Thank you Jason for helping ! 
So yea I'd use the limit definition (but with balls) : so it would be like what Daniel suggested by using an n-sphere and then thanks to the "existing" lower bound that I would define as 1, Can I conclude that it is sufficient to be lowerly bounded ?
Here's how I'd write it : 
$\lim_{x\to\infty}=\infty \iff$
$ \forall x\in \mathbb{R^n}, \exists R \gt 0, B(x,R) \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ $\iff$ $\lVert f(x) \rVert \gt R$ and if $R=1$ so $\lVert f(x) \rVert \gt 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will apply:

> If $C$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $g:C\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
>   is continuous then some $x_{0}\in C$ exist such that $g\left(x_{0}\right)=\inf_{x\in C}g\left(x\right)$.

(If you need explanation of this then let me know)

Find some constant $c\geq0$ such that $\left\Vert x\right\Vert >c$
implies that $f\left(x\right)\geq f\left(0\right)$. From $\lim_{\left\Vert x\right\Vert \rightarrow\infty}f\left(x\right)=+\infty$ it follows that such a $c$ indeed exists.

Define $C=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\mid\left\Vert x\right\Vert \leq c\right\} $
and notice that $C$ is compact (bounded and closed) and contains $0$.

If $\iota:C\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$
denotes its inclusion then $g=f\circ\iota:C\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
is a continuous function and we can apply what is mentioned above.

Taking into account that $f$ and $g$ coincide on $C$ there will exist some $x_{0}\in C$ with $f\left(x_{0}\right)=\inf_{x\in C}f\left(x\right)$.

For $x\notin C$ we have $f\left(x\right)\geq f\left(0\right)\geq f\left(x_{0}\right)$.

This together
shows that $\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}}f\left(x\right)=f\left(x_{0}\right)$ and consequently $f$ is bounded lowerly.

Comment: Thank you for your help drhab !
So this is how i understand your first quote, because $C$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $g$ is a continuous function on this compact and with value in $\mathbb{R}$, then $g$ is bounded and reaches its supremum and infimum so you took $x_0\in C$ so that $g(x_0)=\inf_{x\in C}g(x)$ 


From then, I think I am missing some knowledge as I noticed in comments below. I thought I could consider the limit $\lim_{\lVert x\rVert \to \infty}f(x)$ as a common one but it seems it's not the case. I looked into my topology course I can't fin it. What this limit name?

Comment: You should read the expression $\lim_{\left\Vert x\right\Vert \rightarrow\infty}f\left(x\right)=+\infty$
not as a limit but as an abbreviation of: $\forall r\in\mathbb{R}\exists c\in\mathbb{R}\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\left[\left\Vert x\right\Vert >c\Rightarrow f\left(x\right)>r\right]$,
i.e. for every $r\in\mathbb{R}$ some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ exists such
that $\left\Vert x\right\Vert >c\Rightarrow f\left(x\right)>r$ is
true for any $x$. I don't know a name for it.

Comment: The image of a compact set under a continuous function is compact.
In our case $g\left(C\right)\subset\mathbb{R}$ is compact. Then it
is bounded so if $g\left(C\right)\neq\emptyset$ and $m=\inf g\left(C\right)$
then $m\in\mathbb{R}$. Also it is closed wich leads to $m\in g\left(C\right)$.
This together tells us that $m=g\left(x_{0}\right)$ for some $x_{0}\in C$.

Comment: oh alright I'll keep in notes. Thank you for the definition !
For next well if I take the definition you gave me, stating that $c\geq 0$ should be okay because $ \lVert x\rVert\rightarrow\infty$
and it would be: $\lVert x\rVert\gt c\geq 0\implies f(x)\gt f(0)$ with $f(0)=r$ so such $c$ exists.
To define $C$ I would show $\complement_\mathbb{R^n} C$ is an open interval so $C$ is closed and bounded set, so is a compact.
Then for the coincidence of $f$ and $g$ if I'm not wrong, you're using Weierstrass theorem to declare that $f(x_0)=\min_{x\in C}f(x)$
Is that correct to justify what you said ?

Comment: As far as I know the Weierstrass extreme value theorem states that a real-valued continuous function on interval $[a,b]$ attains a minimum and a maximum. More generally this is also true if the domain is a compact set $C$. That is used here.

Comment: alright it's very clear ! just one last question : which chapter do you find the abbreviation you told me ?
Thank you very much !

Comment: Well, here I have to dissappoint you. No idea. The expression just made me say directly: 'oh, with this they of course mean to say that..' Also the name Weierstrass didn't play a part in my thinking about it. Succes in your search for the details. You are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some remarks and hints:  First, it seems that the second statement (the greatest lower bound is achieved) implies the first statement (there is a lower bound).

Secondly, for any number $c$ you can divide up the domain as
$$\mathbb{R}^n = \left\{x\mid f(x) \leq c \right\} \cup \left\{x\mid f(x) > c\right\}$$
Using the limit at $\infty$ you should be able to show one of these sets is compact.

Comment: thank you for answering Matthew !
so if I use the definition of the limit of my function it would be like : because $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ so it means that $\forall\epsilon\gt0$, $\forall c\in\mathbb{R^n} \exists x_0\in\mathbb{R^n}$, $x\gt x_0 | f(x)\gt c$ so $inf_{x\in\mathbb{R^n}}f(x)$ is reached by $c$ and 1st question would be answered at the same time. Do you agree ?

Comment: @Brocolus: not quite.  Your statement has an extraneous $\forall\epsilon>0$ in it, and is comparing points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the $>$ relation so it doesn't quite parse.  Look up that definition and make sure sure you understand it before proceeding.

Comment: oh yea my bad I've forgotten to delete the epsilon stuff.
hum I really messed it up, I think it should be better this way : $lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=+\infty \iff$ $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}, \exists x_0 \in \mathbb{R^n}, x \gt x_0 | f(x) \gt c$
is keeping $c$ as my lower bound enough ?

Comment: @Brocolus: Can you explain in words what you mean by "$x>x_0 | f(x) > c$"?

Comment: well because my limit is divergent, so at a certain point, when i get over a value $x_0$ corresponding to $f(x_0)=c$, from this point, my function will be divergent

Comment: @Brocolus: I think I understand what you are trying to say but that's not the definition of $\lim_{\Vert x\Vert \to\infty} f(x) = \infty$.  Are you reading from a book?  If so, look up the definition in that book and make sure you understand it.

Comment: uhm not really I find courses on the internet and i just found an exam sheet in boxes. Which chapter can I find this definition ? 
I could try this way but it's a dead end : $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$ so it means : $x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\.\\.\\.\\x_n\end{pmatrix}$ and then i could take $\lVert x \rVert _\infty$ to use but it goes nowhere